# How to encode a StringBody?

Tags: android, encoding

I have a problem when I want to create a StringBody which contains a "ñ" or any extended character. I need to encode it to UTF-8 and I have tried to define the Charset (UTF-8) like this:

```
new StringBody(i.getValue(), Charset.forName(HTTP.UTF_8));
```

It doesn't work. Are there any way to encode this String body to UTF-8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a snippet working with string data type. Try to change the String to StringBody. Hope it works.

```
String name = "John";
String encodedName = URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8");
```